# Tabla en html y css

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo una tabla en html y le tengo un poco de css y quiero que el th de "Player" ocupe todo el lugar del tr en su espacio

adjunto mi tabla para más detalle.

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Player</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">TR-7</th>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>4,569</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Khiresh Odo</th>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>7,223</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Mia Oolong</th>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>6,219</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: ¿te refieres a un atributo colspan="3" en ese th?

Comment: Sii, gracias... eso me faltaba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso se soluciona con un **colspan**, según la cantidad de celdas que siguen abajo, entiendo que es la cabecera de tu tabla y quedaría con un colapsan de 3, ya que en la siguiente fila es de 3 **td**, y secciona tu tabla para que te sea mas facil identificar los bloques que la conforman, *thead, tbody, tfoot* y clases para modificar ciertas celdas con estilos, te dejo un pequeño ejemplo:

```css
.titleTable {
  text-align: center;
}

.namePlayer {
  font-weight: bold;
}

tr>td {
  padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="titleTable" colspan="3">Player</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="namePlayer" scope="row">TR-7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>4,569</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="namePlayer" scope="row">Khiresh Odo</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7,223</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="namePlayer" scope="row">Mia Oolong</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>6,219</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias, ya lo pude corregir!!